# Android Textview status is not changing when its relaunched/(minimize to open)

Tags: android, dynamic, textview, auto-update

I followed [this](https://github.com/iammert/RadioPlayerService/blob/master/app/src/main/java/co/mobiwise/myapplication/RadioActivity.java) to Create sample radio stream in android

Over there every thing is fine But When I minimize and re-open the app from notification or directly

The Text view status is not updating Until I click on any button

This the status code

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mRadioManager.connect();
}

@Override
public void onRadioLoading() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //TODO Do UI works here.
            mTextViewControl = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textviewControl);
            mTextViewControl.setText("RADIO STATE : LOADING...");
            mTextViewControl.invalidate();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onRadioConnected() {

}

@Override
public void onRadioStarted() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //TODO Do UI works here.
            mTextViewControl = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textviewControl);
            mTextViewControl.setText("RADIO STATE : PLAYING...");
            mTextViewControl.invalidate();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onRadioStopped() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //TODO Do UI works here
            mTextViewControl = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textviewControl);
            mTextViewControl.setText("RADIO STATE : STOPPED.");
            mTextViewControl.invalidate();
        }
    });
}
```

Here I removed Default text(`android:text="RADIO STATE : IDLE"`) from XML also

But still same issue.
[This](https://github.com/iammert/RadioPlayerService) is the full reference code

**Update 1**

Actually I have a Radio Player [Notification service](https://github.com/iammert/RadioPlayerService/blob/master/library/src/main/java/co/mobiwise/library/radio/RadioPlayerService.java) so when I click on the notification it will open the app from the notification its stating and stopping But when I open app It form the Notification the status of `Textview` is not working

I changed `runOnUiThread(new Runnable()` instead of `mTextViewControl.post(new Runnable()`

But still same issue

Please help me on this kind

Comment: you have to refresh the textview onResume method that is always called when the use return on the activity

Comment: can you suggest my how

Answer (score 0):

use `runonuithread()` instead of `post()`

```
@Override
public void onRadioStarted() {
    mTextViewControl = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textviewControl);
    mTextViewControl.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mTextViewControl.setText("RADIO STATE : STOPPED.");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks @user Karthik Sridharan .....But Still Same issue Please check my updated question